# What's the correct way to use tf.while_loop in a custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I intended to use the following functions as the loss for my training:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def wrap(dist): 
    return tf.while_loop(
        cond=lambda X: tf.math.abs(X) > 0.5,
        body=lambda X: tf.math.subtract(X, 1.0),
        loop_vars=(dist))


# PBC-aware MSE, period = 1.0 ([0, 1.0])
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = tf.math.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    diff = tf.nest.flatten(diff)
    diff = tf.vectorized_map(wrap, diff)
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(diff))

# ...other code for loading data and defining the model

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(momentum=0.1),
              loss=custom_loss)
```

but the I encountered a bunch of error messages. As the log is too long I put them in a gist:
https://gist.github.com/HanatoK/f75fddd82372f499c37279f1128cad7a

The equivalent numpy version of the code above should be

```py
def wrap_diff2(x, y, period=1.0):
    diff = np.abs(x - y)
    while diff > 0.5 * period:
        diff -= period
    return diff * diff

def custom_loss_numpy(y_true, y_pred):
    diff2 = np.vectorize(wrap_diff2)(y_true, y_pred)
    return np.mean(diff2)
```

Any ideas?
The full code example is shared on google colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ExVHgyKHQfGcpXvo5ZsuBBmzmHzxUekC?usp=sharing

Comment: After some debugging I found `tf.nest.flatten` just reshaped the tensor to (1, batch_size), but as in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nest/flatten) it does nothing to tensors. Probably I should use `tf.reshape` here, but still I do not know how to implement the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def wrap(dist): 
    return tf.while_loop(
        cond=lambda X: tf.math.abs(X) > 0.5,
        body=lambda X: tf.math.subtract(X, 1.0),
        loop_vars=(dist))

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = tf.math.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    diff = tf.reshape(diff, [-1])
    diff = tf.vectorized_map(wrap, [diff])
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(diff))

y_true = np.array([[0., 1., 1.0], [0., 0., 0.]])
y_pred = np.array([[1., 1., 1.0], [1., 0., 1.]])
custom_loss(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks, your code snippet works, but I still get a bunch of errors when I tried it in training. I have uploaded the example code on google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ExVHgyKHQfGcpXvo5ZsuBBmzmHzxUekC?usp=sharing

Comment: The error you're now facing is not from this loss function but from the `custom_error`. Change `diff = tf.reshape(diff, [-1]); diff = tf.vectorized_map(wrap, [diff])` inside your custom error function.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am curious. Could you elaborate on how the `tf.reshape` and `tf.vectorized_map(wrap, [diff])` work?

Comment: See the documentation, I couldn't say more than that. If you don't understand, then post a new question regarding that.